# Dynamically Set Model Properties in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a long list of check boxes that I need to display on a form. I get the list of check boxes from a table in the database and render them on the page. When the page is saved, I am saving the field name and value (as they are stored in the database) of each selected item.

I also have a model class that all of these check box fields map to, but I was thinking, since I have the field name and value, I would be able to set only the properties for which I have a field/value.

I was thinking I could just do something like this, but I know the syntax isn't correct:

```
private void CreatePPAIndication(ReferralFormViewModel viewModel, Guid personId, Guid encId)
        {
            var ppaIndication = new PPAIndication();

            ppaIndication.enterprise_id = "00001";
            ppaIndication.practice_id = "0001";
            ppaIndication.person_id = personId;
            ppaIndication.enc_id = encId;
            // set more properties...

            // Here is where I would set a property for each selected check box.
            foreach (var indication in viewModel.Indications.Where(o => o.IsSelected))
            {
                var result = "ppaIndication." + indication.FieldName + "(" + indication.FieldValue + ")";
            }

            // How can I essentially "execute" the string in the line above?

            _context.PPAIndications.Add(ppaIndication);
        }
```

So, basically, I am wondering how I can essentially "execute" the "result" string as real code. Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use reflection for that

something like

```
GetType().GetProperty(o.FieldName).GetValue(indication, null);
```

to get the value

or

```
GetType().GetProperty(o.FieldName).SetValue(indication, o.Value);
```

to set the value

Comment: Easy as that? This looks to be just what I needed. Thank you, Steve!